# how to periodically remove items from ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, layout, android-listview

I have an Activity with List view.

Each item has an expiration date.

When that date passes I want the item to disappear from the UI.

How would you suggest me to develop it?

I have thought:

1) Alarm manger- but would it be efficient to go over the whole list (20+) even if just one item is to be removed?

2) In addition - how will i force the list to refresh? invalidate data - will cause the whole list to redraw and I just want to remove one item

3) maybe a post delay. But then I know how to "send" it to be triggered in X mili, not on a specific date (more cumbersome to convert, not a big deal)

what would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

> 1)Alarm manger- but would it be efficient to go over the **whole list**
>   (20+) even if just one item is to be removed?
>
> 2) In addition - how will i force the list to refresh? invalidate data
>   - will cause the **whole list** to redraw and I just want to remove one item
>
> 3) maybe a post delay. But then I know how to "send" it to be
>   triggered in X mili, not on a specific date (more cumbersome to
>   convert, not a big deal)

when you invalidate your list it dose not mean that your list will be drawn completely it means just visible items will be drawn just 7-8 depends on list item size.

my solution to your problem:

just when your activity create or better in `onRseume` check the date and update your list. when your activity is not shown why do you try to look at date? **you do not have any UI if you do not have any activity.**

Answer (score 0):

You could give an id to the Items in your list. This way their view will not be recreated when the list is updated but only move to their new position. For this to work you would simply need to override

```
public int getPositionForView (View view)
```

and return AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION for the removed item

AlarmManager does not sound like the right tool for this but you could start a new Thread which sleeps for a while an then changes your Data which notifys your Adapter via an Observer/Observable Interface. But do not forget to call Activity.runOnUiThread() or you will recieve an Exception